# Spring security: securing a servlet with XML and session tracking mode URL

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security

I'm trying to replicate some other issue I'm having that may be caused by using Spring Security. However, I'm not even succeeding at securing a simple servlet. For the purposes of replicating the issue I need to use URL-based tracking, not COOKIE-based. Here's the code I've got:

**src/MyServlet.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public final class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hi!");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
    }
}
```

**WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description>Spring Secured</description>
    <display-name>Spring Secured</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SpringSecured</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SpringSecured</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


   <session-config>
     <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
   </session-config>

 </web-app>
```

**WebContent/WEB-INF/spring/security.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

 </beans:beans>
```

This is working fine if I change `<tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>` to `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>`, but for the purposes of reproducing some other bug, I need to set it to `URL`. It's showing me a login form, but when I click "Login", I get a message "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.". What am I missing here?